# how to pass argv in a vector uint8_t

Tags: sockets, hex, buffer, argv, uint8t

in my code I was able to generate a vector uint8_t with hex values inside, as I can pass them out via argv. I enclose the code, how do I pass the components of the "command" vector as parameters of the main function?
I hope I explained myself.

I would like to pass those values in this way:

> ./main 192.168.1.60 0x26 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x26

or also

> ./main 192.168.1.60 2600000026

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// per compilare gcc test.cpp -lstdc++ -o main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, n;
    int connected = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char sendline[5];
    char recvline[5];
    std::string serveraddr = argv[1];

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(9761);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    uint8_t command[] = {0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x26}; 
    int bytes_to_send = sizeof(command);

    //cout << command;
    send(sockfd, command, bytes_to_send, 0);
    recv(sockfd, command, bytes_to_send, 0);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Looping over the `argv` array converting strings to bytes? Do you know how to use a `for` loop?  Do you know how to parse strings? Have a look at [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), setting its `base` parameter to 0 (auto-detect) or 16 (hex).

Comment: the answer is a little articulated, look at the post below. Thanks